# java.io.NotSerializableException when creating state in Corda V3.1

Tags: serialization, deserialization, corda

when migrating from Corda V2 to Corda V3.1. Unable to save or create state, getting below exception no constructor for serialization found but the contract state has a default constructor and parmatrised constructor.

```
[WARN ] 2018-04-12T17:40:09,773Z [Node thread-1] flow.[f1e07b24-6f07-4e2b-a9cf-c9f92c14985a].run - Terminated by unexpected exception {}
java.io.NotSerializableException: net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState -> data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> No constructor for deserialization found for class com.demo.project.nodes.states.ContractState.
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationHelperKt.constructorForDeserialization(SerializationHelper.kt:50) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer.<init>(ObjectSerializer.kt:19) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory$makeClassSerializer$1.apply(SerializerFactory.kt:271) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory$makeClassSerializer$1.apply(SerializerFactory.kt:40) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory.makeClassSerializer(SerializerFactory.kt:255) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializerFactory.get(SerializerFactory.kt:100) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput.writeObject$node_api(SerializationOutput.kt:98) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput.writeObjectOrNull$node_api(SerializationOutput.kt:93) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.PropertySerializer$DescribedTypePropertySerializer.writeProperty(PropertySerializer.kt:84) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer$writeObject$$inlined$ifThrowsAppend$lambda$1$1.invoke(ObjectSerializer.kt:66) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer$writeObject$$inlined$ifThrowsAppend$lambda$1$1.invoke(ObjectSerializer.kt:17) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationHelperKt.withList(SerializationHelper.kt:401) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer$writeObject$$inlined$ifThrowsAppend$lambda$1.invoke(ObjectSerializer.kt:64) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer$writeObject$$inlined$ifThrowsAppend$lambda$1.invoke(ObjectSerializer.kt:17) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationHelperKt.withDescribed(SerializationHelper.kt:390) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.ObjectSerializer.writeObject(ObjectSerializer.kt:62) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput.writeObject$node_api(SerializationOutput.kt:106) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput.writeObject$node_api$default(SerializationOutput.kt:97) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput.writeObject$node_api(SerializationOutput.kt:78) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput$_serialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationOutput.kt:64) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput$_serialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationOutput.kt:22) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationHelperKt.withList(SerializationHelper.kt:401) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput$_serialize$1.invoke(SerializationOutput.kt:63) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput$_serialize$1.invoke(SerializationOutput.kt:22) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationHelperKt.withDescribed(SerializationHelper.kt:390) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput._serialize$node_api(SerializationOutput.kt:62) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.SerializationOutput.serialize(SerializationOutput.kt:36) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.serialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:128) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$serialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:126) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$serialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$serialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:126) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$serialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.serialize(SerializationScheme.kt:126) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationAPIKt.serialize(SerializationAPI.kt:221) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationAPIKt.serialize$default(SerializationAPI.kt:220) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.WireTransaction$Companion.createComponentGroups(WireTransaction.kt:242) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder$toWireTransactionWithContext$1.invoke(TransactionBuilder.kt:114) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder$toWireTransactionWithContext$1.invoke(TransactionBuilder.kt:36) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core(TransactionBuilder.kt:113) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core$default(TransactionBuilder.kt:97) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:95) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toLedgerTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:135) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.verify(TransactionBuilder.kt:143) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at com.demo.project.nodes.initiators.ContractStateFlowInitiator.call(ContractStateFlowInitiator.java:54) ~[project-node-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.demo.project.nodes.initiators.ContractStateFlowInitiator.call(ContractStateFlowInitiator.java:25) ~[project-node-1.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
```

---

> ```
> Corda version :corda_release_version = '3.1-corda'
> Corda Gradle Plugin Version: corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.1.0'
> Quasar Version: quasar_version = '0.7.9'
> Boot Version :spring_boot_version = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
> ```

---

The error occurs at the time of verifying the contract in ContractStateFlowInitiator class: txBuilder.verify(getServiceHub());

Things worked with Version 2.0

Error persists even with corda version 3.0. I tried renaming my state com.demo.project.nodes.states.ContractState to  com.demo.project.nodes.states.DemoContractState also created a default constructor in the state but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate your parameterized  constructor with **@ConstructorForDeserialization**

Though the java doc mentions using annotation[@CordaConstructor] -- java doc needs to be updated in SerializationHelper.Kt

In some cases, it's also seen that notary should also 've the shared project.

Also make sure to add -parmeters to all sub projects
eg:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also did not work with V3 source that was working on V2.
And the same Exception occurred.
I think that the contents of StackTrace are somewhat different, but I think that it will be helpful.

[Corda V3 Error java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727444/corda-v3-error-java-util-concurrent-executionexception)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above mentioned solution to add @ConstructorForDeserialization on the constructor of the class, we need to make some change in the IDE setting.

Fix: In IntelliJ:

```
Open the settings:
Windows: File -> Settings
osX: IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences...
Go to Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
Write -parameters in the Additional command line parameters field
Completely rebuild the project (Build -> Rebuild Project)
```

reference is this corda bootcamp link : https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp/wiki/Troubleshooting

[image]